# disable hover effect for touch devices - javascript

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

In my application, there are multiple cards to show different details. Now, there are two paddles(left/right) to scroll cards . For normal browsing(safari,firefox,chrome) in desktop/laptop, that left/right paddles are visible while hovering over those cards. Inside those cards all the link/hyperlink are working fine in desktop/laptop.

But, when i check that same application in ipad, we had to double click for any link on those cards. Because on first click those paddles are visible then on second click those link routes to the correct path. I want to disable that hover effect and show the paddles initially.

**here is my template code snippet**

```
<div
          v-show="grid"
          class="second-row"
          @mouseover="showPaddle"
          @scroll.passive="setScrolledLeft"
        >
          <Paddles
            :margin-top="secondRowHeight/2"
            :showRightPaddle="showRightPaddle"
            :showLeftPaddle="showLeftPaddle"
            @scroll-cards="scrollCards"
          /> ..... </div>
```

Now, i am trying to check the touch devices and remove the hover effect on paddles and display them.

**method to show paddles**

```
    // checking the device is touch or non-touch
   isTouchDevice() {
    if ('ontouchstart' in window ||
       (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof window.DocumentTouch) ||
       (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)
    ) {
        return true;
      }
        return window.matchMedia( "(pointer: coarse)" ).matches;
    },
    showPaddle() {
      const secondRowEl = this.$el.querySelector('.second-row');
      const gridWidth = this.$el.querySelector('.grid').clientWidth; // to scroll cards
      const scrollMax = gridWidth - secondRowEl.clientWidth;
      if (gridWidth > secondRowEl.clientWidth) {
        if (secondRowEl.scrollLeft > 0 && secondRowEl.scrollLeft < scrollMax) {
          this.showLeftPaddle = true;
          this.showRightPaddle = true;
          if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
          if(this.isTouchDevice) {
            try {
              for (let sheetI = document.styleSheets.length - 1; sheetI >= 0; sheetI-=1) {
                const sheet = document.styleSheets[sheetI];
                if (sheet.cssRules) {
                  for (let ruleI = sheet.cssRules.length - 1; ruleI >= 0; ruleI-=1) {
                    const rule = sheet.cssRules[ruleI];
                    if (rule.selectorText) {
                      if (sheet.rules[ruleI].selectorText.match(':hover')) {
                        sheet.deleteRule(ruleI);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            } catch(e) {
              Logger.error(e);
            }
          }
        }
        } else if (secondRowEl.scrollLeft >= scrollMax) {
          this.showLeftPaddle = true;
          this.showRightPaddle = false;
        } else if (secondRowEl.scrollLeft <= 0) {
          this.showLeftPaddle = false;
          this.showRightPaddle = true;
        }
      } else {
        this.showLeftPaddle = false;
        this.showRightPaddle = false;
      }
      if (!this.secondRowHeight) {
        this.secondRowHeight = secondRowEl.offsetHeight;
      }
    }
```

How will i solve that @mouseover issue and display paddles normally ?

Comment: it is working fine for all browser(safari/chrome/ff) but while checking on ipad that same application we have to double click on link.

Comment: That's because Apple devices don't trigger any `click`-like events (including `tap` and other touch events) on invisible items. To get around it use `opacity: .01` on the paddles instead of `display: none` (which is what `v-if` does). But in this case you should have asked about that. You never said anything about iPad in your question.